# Unity Slider doesn't apply changes automatically

Tags: user-interface, events, unity-game-engine, 3d, editor

I've created custom Editor with Slider:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CylindricalCamera))]
public class CylindricalCameraEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        CylindricalCamera camera = (CylindricalCamera)target;
        camera._nearClipPlane = EditorGUILayout.Slider(camera._nearClipPlane, 0, 10);
```

In CylindricalCamera I am drawing a custom gizmo:

```
public class CylindricalCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
..
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
...
```

I want a gizmo in CylindricalCamera to be repainted every time I drag the slider. But in fact I have not only to drag the slider, but also to select and press Enter on the textbox near the Slider:

[Custom slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RofJo.png)

How could I force Slider to apply changes automatically, without pressing Enter?

I am using Unity 5.3.5 f1

Comment: Have you tried putting a Debug.Log in the `OnInspectorGUI` method to determine if the value you're getting from slider actually changes?

Comment: Also, be aware that you're using the old custom editor w target; see a new example with serialized properties in the official documentation (topmost block of code): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html

Comment: From logs it seems that camera._nearClipPlane is changing immediately, but OnDrawGizmos() function is calling with delay.  It seems that only entering value in textbox leads to OnDrawGizmos() call. Moreover, there is no OnSceneGUI function in Editor (undocumented)!

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
OnInspectorGUI()
{
...
if (GUI.changed) EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat